# Windows 10 is still shutting down

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-10, shutdown

Apparently I closed my laptop too soon after turning it off. And now, when i tried to turn it on, it shows me, that laptop is still shutting down. I tried to restart my laptop using keyboard shortcuts, but it doesn't shut down.

Comment: Hold the power button, or remove the power and battery. Little else you can try in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, holding the power button will shutdown the system, as will removing the battery.

After this the system should boot up correctly, if it does not, just modify your question and I will be happy to help.

You obviously identified the easiest way to prevent a recurrence of this problem - not closing the lid during the shutdown phase. However, should you wish to, it may be worth right clicking on your battery icon in the tray (lower right corner), clicking on power options, and then selecting "Choose what closing the lid does" - setting this to "Do nothing" allows you to safely close the lid as soon as you have issued the shutdown command. Hope this helps.